# Other methods to determine the page size of an external pdf?

Tags: graphics, pdf, lengths

I would like to query the page size of an external PDF in a document.

I can box an included PDF and measure the box (with or without actually using the box), as shown in the MWE, but I'm wondering if there's a more direct method that could be used without actually using `\includegraphics{}` on the PDF.

The ideal solution would be similar to using `\pdflastximagepages` to get the number of pages in a PDF.

### MWE (using a boxing/measuring solution):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe,printlen}
\uselengthunit{in}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox{\mybox}{\includegraphics{example-image-a.pdf}}
The width is \printlength{\wd\mybox} and the height is \printlength{\ht\mybox}.

\usebox{\mybox}
\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Well if you want to measure the dimensions of a picture or a pdf file before include it inside your document there are a lot of options for do it.

Directly from the won pdf and using LaTeX you can use the [eso-pic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) package for add a grid to you pdf obtained with LaTeX. Or also using the correct options in Adobe Reader or another pdf viewer.

Comment: @Aradnix, thanks, I know all these methods, but they do not answer my question. :-)

Comment: `pdftex` (and probably also `xetex`) only fetch image dimensions through a `\pdfximage`, so you need some form of `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires `-shell-escape` and `pdfinfo`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{cm}

\newcommand{\getpdfinfo}[1]{%
  \openin\pdfread="|pdfinfo #1"
  \begingroup\endlinechar=-1
  \loop\ifeof\pdfread
  \else
    \read\pdfread to \infoline
    \processinfoline
  \repeat
  \endgroup
}

\newread\pdfread

\def\processinfoline{%
  \ifx\infoline\empty
  \else
    \expandafter\extractinfoline\infoline\extractinfoline
  \fi
}

\def\extractinfoline#1: #2\extractinfoline{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\def\pdfboundingbox#1{%
  \getpdfinfo{#1}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\getboundingbox\csname Page size\endcsname\getboundingbox
}
\def\getboundingbox#1 x #2 pts#3\getboundingbox{%
  \setlength{\PDFWD}{#1bp}\setlength{\PDFHT}{#2bp}%
}
\newlength{\PDFWD}\newlength{\PDFHT}


\begin{document}

\pdfboundingbox{seti.pdf}

Width is \printlength{\PDFWD}, height is \printlength{\PDFHT}

\end{document}
```

One could just extract the bounding box information, but having also the complete report may be handy.

The PDF file is one I just compiled for an example and is in A4 format. The bad rounding is due to `printlen`.

[image]